# Keras CNN model is throwing as error message as 'ValueError: Layer 'conv1d_12' expected 2 variables, but received 0 variables during loading'

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement a CNN model to help predict kidney stones. Now, this model is running as expected on my local machine, but when I try deploying the app over Streamlit Cloud, it is throwing error:

> ValueError: Layer 'conv1d_12' expected 2 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['conv1d_12/kernel:0', 'conv1d_12/bias:0']

What would be leading to this issue?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = df1[['gravity', 'ph', 'osmo', 'cond', 'urea', 'calc', 'osmo_cond_ratio', 'urea_calc_diff', 'osmo_urea_interaction', 'gravity_bin', 'ph_bin', 'osmo_bin', 'cond_bin', 'urea_bin', 'calc_bin']]
y = df1['target']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=None)

X_train = np.reshape(X_train.to_numpy(), (X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1))
X_test = np.reshape(X_test.to_numpy(), (X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1))

model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv1D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))\
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))\
model.add(Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=3, padding='same', activation='relu'))\
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)))\
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(64)))model.add(Dropout(0.2))
```